# All BCD edits lost after reboot

Tags: vhd, bcdedit

I'm trying to create a system that will use native boot VHDs, [as described on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg318055(WS.10).aspx).

I followed that entire whitepaper throughout, making modifications for my system (I have three VHDs to boot from).  I completed Step 13 and pulled the flash drive before rebooting.  After booting I got an error: BOOTMGR Missing. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> to reboot your system.

The only thing remaining on my system are the three VHD files I copied over.  All the BCD entries I made are gone, the VDISKs I created in `DISKPART` are gone, etc.

Is there an implicit "save your work by typing this command" step that I'm missing?  I went over everything again and I don't see that I'm missing anything.